# Tensor product of a local ring and a regular local ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

This lemma comes from *Grothendieck's FGA Explained*.
[image]

I have two questions.

(1) Use of Nakayama's lemma

It seems to me that, for example, to show $K \otimes  R=0  \Rightarrow K=0$, I need to show $R= S/ m_A S = (A \otimes_k R)/(m_A \otimes_k R)$. But I don't know if $m_A \otimes_k R$ is the Jacobson radical?

(2) Why is $M \otimes_S R=M \otimes_A k$

To me, $M \otimes_S R= M \otimes_{A \otimes_k R} (A \otimes_k R)/(m_A \otimes_k R)$. I don't know how to continue and why the tensor product is over $A$.

-----------------------update------------------------------

$k$ is the residue field for $A$. I see why it's trivial if we can show $M \otimes_S R=M \otimes_A k$. (I'm misled by $K \otimes_S R$ there). Then it all boils down to the second part.

Comment: I don’t understand why it boils down to the second part. By assumption $M$ is a finitely generated $S$-module. Is it also finitely generated as an $A$-module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, $R=A/m\otimes_kR=k\otimes_A(A\otimes_kR)$, and then $$R\otimes_SM=k\otimes_A(A\otimes_kR)\otimes_{A\otimes_kR}M=k\otimes_AM.$$