# Lemma 7.1.8 in Grothendieck’s FGA Explained

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I have the same question as (1) of [Tensor product of a local ring and a regular local ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1623012/tensor-product-of-a-local-ring-and-a-regular-local-ring), which comes from Grothendieck’s FGA Explained.[image: Lemma 7.1.8] I don’t understand why we can apply Nakayama’s lemma here, for if the use of Nakayama is for $S$-modules, then we need to show $m_A\otimes_kR$ is contained in the Jacobson radical of $S$; if it is Nakayama for $A$-modules, then we need $M$ to be finitely generated over $A$. However, I don’t know how to show either of above. Do I miss something obvious?

In fact, this lemma is used to show: if $X$ is a smooth projective variety over an algebraically closed field $k$ and $\mathcal{E}$ is a coherent sheaf on $X\times S$, flat over $S$, such that for every
$s\in S$ the restriction $\mathcal{E}_{X\times\{s\}}$ to the fiber is locally free, then $\mathcal{E}$ is locally free. Any proof of this statement would also be appreciated.

Comment: Which use of Nakayama’s lemma are you concerned about? The first or the second one? Neither case requires $M$ to be finitely generated over $A$. By the way, this question would be improved if it were self-contained, that is, didn’t rely on the link to the other question (you can keep it, but as an illustration – not as a problem statement).

Comment: @Pheobe - Since $X$ is projective and the fiber $X_s:=X\times\{s\} \cong X$ is projective, you should also include a proof of the claim that "$E_{X_s}$ locally free implies $E$ locally free" - How do you prove this claim?

Comment: @Aphelli Thank you for the advice, I’ll edit it in a while. I am concerned about both. I think if the use of Nakayama is for $S$-modules, then we need to show $m_A\otimes_{k}R$ is contained in the Jacobson radical of $S$; if it is Nakayama for $A$-modules, then we need $M$ to be finitely generated. Could you please explain why neither case requires $M$ to be finitely generated over $A$?